# How do I create a custom page in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I have a website here that I need to create a custom page where in I can call the header and the footer as well as the sidebar.

If you're going to do it in Wordpress its easy as this link says: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

However, Joomla is a bit different on this one. If I will try to add a new article I wont be able to customize the layout that I want. Let's say in the custom page I want to create I don't want the footer to show up and I want to add internal CSS on it which is possible on Wordpress custom page.

Any idea how do the same thing Joomla 1.5??

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to make something for Joomla 1.5, because they are at Joomla 3.x

Comment: Joomla 1.5 has been past end of life for years and years. However I will say that I never had any problem making customized displays in 1.5, you need to plan out what modules you want on what pages and 1.5 supported layout overrides and multiple templates plus you could always use a plugin or an "if" to conditionally load css.